# Handling an empty path variable request

Tags: json, spring, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a scenario where I can take a student Id as input via a part variable and return some data back as JSON objects where JavaScript handles the response as a part of AJAX call.

Suppose the method is called like:

```
 /student/{studentId}
```

where studentId is a path variable in Spring MVC web service declaration. Now for requests to /student, the front end gets a "404 Not Found" error.

Where should this be handled on the front end or I should create a new method and map it to the /student call and then throw a custom exception?

Comment: For a REST endpoint I'd expect `/students/<id>`(note plural form), and for a GET to `/students` to provide a list of *all* students. The method of the front end should probably throw an error without even *calling* the backend if it isn't given an ID to use.

Answer (score 2):

Front-End should validate user input based on requirements of the back-end, so if a route need a primary key or any other parameter, front-end should check and ask the user for that parameter and call API, as defined in it, 's the route, always with `id`,
of the curse in back-end this should consider that if no `id` provided, return a proper error.